# Observable.FromAsyncPattern() is stuck

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am trying to download some data from WCF using RX. However `Observable.FromAsyncPattern()` doesn't return any response when combind using `SelecMany`

I have tried to highlight this problem in the snippet below:

```
var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var obs = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<PictureFile>(ServiceClient.BeginDownloadFilePreview, ServiceClient.EndDownloadFilePreview);

obs().Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine("I am here"));

var result = from _ in timer
             from data in obs()
             select data;

result.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine("Can't get here :( "));
```

So if understand RX and `SelecMany` correctly, code above should print:

*"I am here"*

*"Can't get here :( "*

However it only prints the first line and not the second one

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that this code runs fine without a debugger attached, but fails if I run it without debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it!

Firstly I shouldn't have *swallowed* exceptions, even though it was a testing code and should have logged all exceptions reported by IObservable.

Secondly I was running my project from MSUnit tests and when running it with an attached dubugger it affected the maxReceivedMessageSize of WCF binding (at least it looks like it), so when I was running in Debug mode it all worked, but when running without it one request failed, but I haven't seen it as I wasn't checkin OnError messages.

Lesson learnt: Always Log OnError messages